# Xcode signing issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I thought this was a thing of the past, but somehow I got some weird problem with CodeSign again when building for debug.

I have set both the Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile correctly. I can build another project with the same Identity/Provisioning combination without any problem.

CodeSign basically fails with the message "no identity found":

```
CodeSign /Users/hans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeedBoxHD-enwifuhucowlkvggoqexfgsyhnst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SpeedBox\ Free\ copy.app
    cd /Users/hans/sync/workspace/iPhone/SpeedBox/SpeedBoxHD
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Hans Schneider (YR68TPB9AQ)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: *"
                      (0b0bdc0d-e25f-4996-a41a-c44091b7372e)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 5A2FC3B3A95FBA926C30606701B59592910FC159 --entitlements /Users/hans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeedBoxHD-enwifuhucowlkvggoqexfgsyhnst/Build/Intermediates/SpeedBoxHD.build/Debug-iphoneos/Speed\ Box\ Free\ copy.build/SpeedBox\ Free\ copy.app.xcent /Users/hans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeedBoxHD-enwifuhucowlkvggoqexfgsyhnst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SpeedBox\ Free\ copy.app

5A2FC3B3A95FBA926C30606701B59592910FC159: no identity found
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Where does this hash ("5A2…") come from anyway? Is this calculated based on the selected Identity and app? And what does the hash of the provisioning profile ("0b0…") mean? It is different from the one in the project that builds.

Here is the CodeSign output of the project that builds with the same settings:

```
usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Hans Schneider (YR68TPB9AQ)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: *"
                      (bf0b4cbb-a0b8-41a9-9ed6-c9e9a85ca242)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 0C05CF8475D17E3C59F69BFF07A30D1B6FE16FBE --entitlements /Users/hans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DoggyCam-dtumjmdbsaagfvgykfclguwaqeds/Build/Intermediates/DoggyCam.build/Debug-iphoneos/DoggyCam.build/DoggyCam.app.xcent /Users/hans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DoggyCam-dtumjmdbsaagfvgykfclguwaqeds/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DoggyCam.app

/Users/hans/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DoggyCam-dtumjmdbsaagfvgykfclguwaqeds/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DoggyCam.app: replacing existing signature
```

I know posting this problem here is kind of a long shot, because you probably would have to take a deep look at the settings but I have been working on it for days now and can't seem to find a solution. The project that does not build is Objective C with some Swift code. Could this be the problem?  Unfortunately I don't really know at what point the project failed to build, it must have been around the time when I installed Xcode 6.3.1 though…

At the moment the only idea I have is creating a new Signing Identity and try it with this one…

Comment: Try `Select Team` from Build Settings -> General, it will refresh your list, clean remove all assignments of profiles choose Don't Sign, build, after error choose from refreshed list. It should work.

Comment: The hash is your provisioning's identifier. I would go to "Settings > Account > Select your Apple ID > View Details" and refresh the provisioning list. Then go back to the Build settings, and re-set the provisioning.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, that refreshed all my provisioning profiles and the project now builds.

Comment: Now the hashes are the same in both projects too, btw… Thanks again! :)